# Get the list of elements in a div class

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenide

I have multiple div classes. I need to get the inner div elements of the text values.

```
<div data-tab-content-id="2" class="panel active">
  <div class="_1jkaeae">
      <div class="abc-table">
          <div class="aaa nhc">
              <div class="aaa-name">Hello</div>
          </div>
          <div class="aaa mhjss">
              <div class="aaa-name">How</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="aaa qwqwq">
          <div class="aaa-name">are</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aaa kkkk">
      <div class="aaa-name">You</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aaa cccc">
  <div class="aaa-name">doing</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="aaa cvdsdws">
  <div class="aaa-name">Welcome</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="aaa klqwq">
  <div class="aaa-name">to the web</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

From the above html the output I am looking for is to get all the text values (Hello,How,are,you,doing,welcome,to the web).

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

`How,are,you,doing,welcome,to the web` they all share same class name, you can go ahead with **class name**, **css selector**, or **xpath** .

You can use this css selector :

```
.aaa-name
```

Code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".aaa-name")).getText();
```

Xpath would be :

```
//div[@class='aaa-name']
```

**Code :**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='aaa-name']")).getText();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The texts you are looking for belong to the same class name. So you can find the texts using the `className` method.
You can find it like:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("aaa-name")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

As they all share same class names, You need to get all elements using the class name i.e `aaa-name` and then loop through elements to get desired output. e.g:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("aaa-name"));
for(WebElement element: elements){
    //perform your logic here...
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets divide the problems in steps:

1. Get list of all the div elements for which you need text

   ```
   List<WebElement> ele_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='aaa-name']"))
   ```
2. Loop through above list and get the text of each element from above list and print:

   ```
   List<String> text_element = new ArrayList<String>()
   for(WebElement ele : ele_list){
       text_element.add(ele.getText());
   }
   ```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you @Popeye.your solution worked. but I am facing another issue. After getting the texts I need to assert them. Here is the code I tried.

Comment: @newbie you can have the expected data saved in a list and can add assert in the for loop itself. for e.g. `Assert.assertEquals(ele.getText(), "<expected Text>");`

Please add the code that you are trying for assertion in the question itself. Let us have a look and try to figure out if there are any issues in it.

Comment: @newbie if the above answer works for you, could you mark it as answer by clicking the hollow under vote down arrow please?

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` and use the following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.aaa-name")));
        for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(elements.get(i).getText());

        }
```

**Output on console :**

```
Hello
How
are
You
doing
Welcome
to the web
```